# Integer pairs sequence

Tags: java

I have a sequence of pairs of integers like this:

```
939-2835,
2023-939,
939-943,
943-941,
939-949,
949-947,
939-965,
965-953,
2844-955,
961-2844,
965-961,
965-963,
```

I want to find out the sequence between 2835 and 2844
The answer should like this

```
2835-939-965-961-2844
```

or as pairs:

```
[939-2835],
[939-965],
[965-961],
[961-2844]
```

My research depends on this. Any Ideas?

Comment: What are the exact rules for sequence building?

Comment: How is defined the sequence, a string ? an array of objects ? a list ?

Comment: BFS/DFS could work here.

Comment: You can do this with Dijkstra's algorithm. You will need maps for temporary and permanent labels.

Comment: This is effectively an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: The problem is not completely specified.  It looks like the pairs are non-directed links in a graph.  Is that correct?  Do you need the shortest path, or will any path do?  Which is more important: algorithmic simplicity or efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

[Breadth-First-Search on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Here is an implementation in Java of BFS and DFS available on github.

https://gist.github.com/gennad/791932

You'll probably have to do some reading about how to construct your tree, but once you have a tree of parent/child nodes from your dataset, it should be pretty straight-forward to implement the algorithm.

Wikipedia mentions that there is "Iterative Deepening Depth First Search" which is equivalent but far more memory efficient, should your dataset be huge.
[IDDFSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)